# how to test method with resultSet and preparedStatement

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, resultset

i would like to unit test my method, which return from database id of last inserted object:

```java
     public int getLastId() throws SQLException {
        String query = "select LAST_INSERT_ID();";
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        int id = -1;
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            id = resultSet.getInt("LAST_INSERT_ID()");
        }
        return id;
    }
```

and then i want to do same unit test like this:

```java
    dataBaseService = mock(DataBaseService.class);
        resultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);

     @Test
    public void getLastIdIsCorrect() throws SQLException {
        //given
        int expectedId = 1;
        int expectedIncorrectId = 101;
        //when
        when(resultSet.getInt("LAST_INSERT_ID()")).thenReturn(1);
        when(dataBaseService.getLastId()).thenCallRealMethod();
        int result = dataBaseService.getLastId();
        //then
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedId, result);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(expectedIncorrectId, result);
    }
```

But i'm getting Null pointer exception at line with PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);

Can you explain me please, how to do unit tests like this correctly? I have few methods left with the same problem and i'm still learning unit tests....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you seem to be unclear what you are testing. If you are testing the code of `getLastId` then you should not mock the class containing it - `DataBaseService` - normally. Instead, your test would be a test OF DataBaseService with something like this...

```
Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
PreparedStatement stmt = mock(PreparedStatement.class);
```

...and...

```
when(connection.prepareStatement(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(stmt);
when(stmt.executeQuery()).thenReturn(resultSet);
```

When you are outside of DataBaseService and want to test something that's calling it, then you can mock DataBaseService and simply return a number then. But for testing DataBaseService it's not needed to do something like...

```
dataBaseService = mock(DataBaseService.class);
...
when(dataBaseService.getLastId()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Simply create a new instance of `DataBaseService` and mock the things "inside" it, for example the Connection.

To show some more code, it would be required to know the setup of your class and also which JUnit version you are using.

Comment: Thx for answer, i tried to change and now i'm getting "Communications link failure" like in my answer... :/

Comment: You could static mock the DriverManager but actually that's a bad idea normally. There are different ways to do it better, for example you could give the connection from the outside. Or use a Database Connection Pool. Hard to say without your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thx for your answer :)
i've changed and created DataBaseService object, and then tried to mock everything inside like this:

```
@Test
public void getLastIdIsCorrect() throws SQLException {
    //given
    int expectedId = 1;
    int expectedIncorrectId = 101;
    //when
    when(DriverManager.getConnection(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(connection);
    when(connection.prepareStatement(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(stmt);
    when(stmt.executeQuery()).thenReturn(resultSet);
    int result = dataBaseService.getLastId();
    //then
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedId, result);
    Assert.assertNotEquals(expectedIncorrectId, result);
}
```

and now i'm getting that exception and headache too :D :

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```